# Expo not loading (React-Native) -- null Expo SDK version

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

My app was working till today but now it looks like something happened to version 18 of Expo.
I got this error:

> The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of
>   Expo Client requires at least v20.0.0. The author should update their
>   experience to a newer Expo SDK version.

I then:

- Updated to Expo v20.0.0
- Handled all unmet dependencies
- `yarn cache clean`
- `rm -rf node_modules/`
- Reinstalled local node modules

and I'm still getting the same error.

What do I need to do to get Simulator to recognize that I am using the correct version of Expo?

**Current environment:**

- Expo v20.0.0
- react-native v0.47.0
- Node v8.11.1
- Xcode v9.3
- Mac OS v10.13.4

Comment: what is the version in your `app.json`?

Comment: `"expo": "20.0.0"` @PritishVaidya

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/480#issuecomment-345361673), maybe it'll . help

Comment: It was a good idea, it didn't work though. Even deleting the simulator.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I misread your first comment. And you suspicion was correct, I was missing `"sdkVersion": "20.0.0"` from my `app.json`. Adding it, `rm-rf node_modules && yarn install && yarn run ios --reset-cache` fixed that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @PritishVaidya for helping me figure this out.
The problem was simply that I was missing  `"sdkVersion": "20.0.0"` from my `app.json`. The use of this is lined out in the [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v20.0.0/workflow/configuration).

For example:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "sdkVersion": "20.0.0",
    "privacy": "public"
  }
}
```