# The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of Expo Client requires at least v23.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting this error when launching Expo on my iOS simulator.

> The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of Expo Client requires at least v23.0.0. The author should update their experience to a newer Expo SDK version.

I've seen this answer [Expo not loading (React-Native) -- null Expo SDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721497/expo-not-loading-react-native-null-expo-sdk-version/50686735) but the solution does not work for me.  I already have the sdkVersion in my app.json:

```
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "22.0.0"
  }
```

I tried `yarn upgrade --latest` but still no luck.  Any ideas are appreciated.  I'm using expo-cli --version 1.1.0

Comment: If the sdk is already there, you may try `rm-rf node_modules && yarn install && yarn run ios --reset-cache`

Comment: @PritishVaidya nope that didn't do it.  Could updating my `expo-cli` version work?  I'm afraid to do it, because I don't know how to reverse it and some of my projects launch fine.

Comment: You can try creating a new dummy project, most probably that would work and then replicating the codebase to that. That seems to be the only solution since rest of the stuff seems correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is updating the SDK by making the following changes.

- Close XDE or your exp CLI server
- In app.json, change sdkVersion to "27.0.0"
- In package.json, change these dependencies:

  - react-native to "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz"
  - expo to "^27.0.0"
  - react to ("16.3.1" — this exact version)
  - react-navigation to "1.5.11" (if you use it, and be sure to peruse the release notes)
  - jest-expo to "^27.0.0" (if you use it)
  - sentry-expo did not change from "~1.7.0" (if you use it)
- Delete your project’s node_modules directory and run npm install again (or use Yarn)
- Reopen your project in XDE and press “Restart” to clear the packager cache, or run exp start -c if you use use exp.
- Update the Expo app on your phones from the App Store / Google Play. XDE and exp will automatically update your apps in simulators.

Source: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v27-0-0-is-now-available-898bf1e5b0e4

Comment: npm install and removing old node modules works , thanks

Answer (score 14):

1. Close your Expo CLI server
2. Run `expo upgrade` in your project directory (requires the latest version of expo-cli, you can update with `npm i -g expo-cli`).
3. Make sure to check the breaking changes section of this post!
4. Run `expo start -c`

source: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4

Answer (score 3):

- You need to update package.json "dependencies" object, to version you are attempting to use.

  - You may also need to update app.json if expo sdk version is listed,
    i.e ("sdk":"x.x.x") I removed this line completely for me, as I was not
    sure why it was needed there.
  - Close and reopen editor and emulator
  - Run npm install
  - Run npm start

Answer (score 2):

Same "experience you requested" message launching on iPhone...solved it with;

1) update Expo SDK following...
https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52

2) updating .babelrc to be similar to...
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration

3) did this command too... clears caches, etc... `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf node_modules/&& npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit package.json directly. You need to run the expo command `expo update XX.X.X`

See the [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/#sdk-39)

In my case, it was solved executing: `expo update 39.0.0`