# Problem using Xcode with expo, issue reading the current version?

Tags: node.js, xcode, expo

I was trying to run Expo simulation on Xcode and I kept getting an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKIXr.jpg) saying

```
The experience you requested uses Expo SDK 33.0.0, but this copy of Expo Client requires at least v24.0.0
```

I have updated my expo, expo-cli and node then rebooted my macbook, however I am still getting the same error message.
in my package.json, it says

```
"expo": "^34.0.4",
"jest-expo": "^34.0.4",
```

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287710/the-experience-you-requested-uses-expo-sdk-vnull-but-this-copy-of-expo-client), however it did not fix my problem. Any idea what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your project directory run `expo client:install:ios` or `expo client:install:android`. This will show you a prompt like this:

```
╰─$ expo client:install:ios
? You are currently using SDK 33.0.0. Would you like to install client version
 unknown released for this SDK? (Y/n)
```

Go ahead and press y and a version of the Expo client compatible with SDK 33 will be installed in your simulator.

Comment: when I try that I get """ sending exp://192.168.0.120:19000 to expo client:install:ios...                could not send link. apiV2Error: failed to send SMS: the 'From' number +1 ...... is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender iID"""